# is there any Apple Homekit framework compatible devices?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, homekit, ios-homekit

I am doing some R & D on upcoming apple `Homekit` framework. on the web around we have many devices available which support apple `homekit` framework . but on there technical specification it is not given that it supports apple `homekit`.
Apple `Homekit` framework overview in detail you can find at apple `website`.

**Now my question is :**  Is there any devices available in the market with which i can start development or R & D among those devices :

1. Honeywell Thermostat
2. August Smart Lock.
3. Philips Hue

Reference link : 
[Clik Here](http://techieswagger.com/technology/list-top-homekit-compliant-devices/)

These are some of devices which has rumors around the web to support [Apple homekit framework](http://techieswagger.com/technology/apple-homekit-framework-overview/) .

Comment: Any updates ?? I am still facing same issue. any one for help ? click [here](http://techieswagger.com/technology/apple-homekit-features-home-automation-systems/) for more details about Apple homekit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204903 for a list of homekit-certified devices. Presumably this will be updated by apple as new items arrive on the market.

Old answer, still kinda applicable:

There aren't any accessories on the market at the moment, but there are several companies that are probably working to get products to market. None of the three products you list are compatible with HomeKit, however someone has created a 'bridge' that runs on the mac to forward commands to/from the hue bulb. See https://github.com/KhaosT/HomeKitBridge

Apple does ship a HomeKit Simulator with xCode versions 6+ which allows some limited testing of a home-kit enabled app. The simulator is a bit limited in what it supports, but it should give you some idea of how the system works.

Comment: I think there are version of all of the items you listed that support homekit now. See the link above. In addition, there are some certified hardware platforms that are relatively easy to plug in to homekit. See http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/10/02/apples-homekit-gets-support-from-mediatek-via-iot-chip-sdks-aimed-at-appliances-small-devices